# luaL_len is missing in Lua 5.1

Tags: c++, dll, lua, stack

I write C++ dll for my Lua project. Stackoverflow programmer Josh Parnell was very kind to help me. He gave me a code with `luaL_len()` inside.
But I use a program with Lua 5.1.5 implemented in it. `luaL_len()` is missing in this version.
This is a code:

```
static int forLua_SumArray (lua_State* L) {
// Get the length of the table (same as # operator in Lua)
    int n = luaL_len(L, 1);
    double sum = 0.0;

    // For each index from 1 to n, get the table
    // value as a number and add to sum
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      lua_rawgeti(L, 1, i);
      sum += lua_tonumber(L, -1);
      lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_pushnumber(L, sum);
    return 1; 
}
```

Please help me to do one or both of those Things

1. Use something instead of luaL_len to get size of table coming from Lua to dll
2. To make luaL_len work in my Lua 5.1.5

Answer (score 0):

The Lua 5.1 C API function that is closest to `luaL_len` is [`lua_objlen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_objlen). This function should work in your case.

Anyway, the [Compat5.3 project](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3) implements many of the newer C API functions for the older Lua versions (5.1 and 5.2), and it includes an implementation of `luaL_len` for Lua 5.1. You could use or steal from that code.